# Scala & json4s: How do I filter a json array

Tags: scala, json4s

Array example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joseph"
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter"
  }
]
```

I'd like to filter off objects with names which are not starting with `Jo`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joseph"
  }
]
```

The result might be a String or JValue with json array inside.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `removeField` - removes a field, not an array element. `filterField` - returns a weird list instead of initial JValue and breaks type.

Comment: @Duelist the `remove` sounds promising I can't create a working predicate

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk I use it for performance testing. So Dos attack is exactly what I need

Comment: @PavelZorin Can you accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a direct JSON query mechanism in json4s hence created a case class.
Mappd the JSON -> filtered it -> wrote it back to JSON

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write
import org.json4s.{Formats, ShortTypeHints}
object JsonFIlter {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val formats: AnyRef with Formats = Serialization.formats(ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[PersonInfo])))
    val parseJson :List[PersonInfo] = parse("""[
                                              |  {
                                              |    "name": "John"
                                              |  },
                                              |  {
                                              |    "name": "Joseph"
                                              |  },
                                              |  {
                                              |    "name": "Peter"
                                              |  }
                                              |]""".stripMargin)
      .extract[List[PersonInfo]]
    val output = write(parseJson.filter(p => p.name.startsWith("Jo")))
    println(output)

  }

}

case class PersonInfo(name: String)
```